# Streaming Content constantly updating 8x8 streaming service

Tags: c#, web-services, api, asp.net-web-api, stream

I have tried to create a simple console application.

We have a call system from 8x8 that provide a web streaming API but their documentation is very limited and nothing in C#.

The api service streams call statuses in near real time and I would like to get that 'stream' and be able to read and process it in realtime if possible. The response or Content Type is 'text/html'. But the actual body of the response can be declared as json - sample below:

> {"Interaction":{"attachedData":{"attachedDatum":[{"attachedDataKey":"@pri","attachedDataValue":100},{"attachedDataKey":"callingName","attachedDataValue":999999999999},{"attachedDataKey":"cha","attachedDataValue":99999999999},{"attachedDataKey":"cnt","attachedDataValue":0},{"attachedDataKey":"con","attachedDataValue":0},{"attachedDataKey":"med","attachedDataValue":"T"},{"attachedDataKey":"pho","attachedDataValue":9999999999},{"attachedDataKey":"phoneNum","attachedDataValue":9999999999},{"attachedDataKey":"tok","attachedDataValue":999999999}]},"event":"InteractionCreated","inboundChannelid":9999999999,"interactionEventTS":9999999,"interactionGUID":"int-15b875d0da2-DJOJkDhDsrh3AIaFP8VkICv9t-phone-01-testist","resourceType":0}}

I have seen several posts concerning httpClient and the GetAsync methods but none of these appear to work as they appear to be for calls when a response is made, not something that constantly has a response.

Using fiddler for the call it does not appear to close so the stream is constantly running, so fiddler does not display any data until a separate user or instance connects.

When I use a browser the content is 'streamed' to the page and updates automatically and shows all the content (as above).

The api contains authentication so when another client connects and retrieves data the connected client closes and finally I am able to see the data that was gathering.

This is the code so and does return the big stream when another client connects but ideally I want a real time response and appears to just get stuck in the GETASYNC method:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(address, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);


            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var responseContent = response.Content;


                string responseString = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();



                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }
```

Hopefully that's enough information for one of you clever people to help me in my predicament.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also having an issue consuming their streaming API and the examples I found that worked with the Twitter and CouchBase streaming API's did not work with 8x8.  Both Twitter and CouchBase send line terminators in their pushes so the solution relied on ReadLine to pull in the feed.  Since 8x8 does not send terminators you'll need to use ReadBlock or better ReadBlockAsync.

The following code shows how to connect using credentials and consume their feed:

```
private static async Task StreamAsync(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential {UserName = username, Password = password},
            PreAuthenticate = true
        };

        // Client can also be singleton
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            request.Headers.Connection.Add("keep-alive");

            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(
                request,
                HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                using (var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(body))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var buffer = new char[1024];
                            await reader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            Console.WriteLine(new string(buffer));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey there,Thanks for this. 

My issue was combined with the fact they didn't give me the correct url for the streaming compared to their online rubbish documentation. A quick question with this read block does this read to the end of a call? Or would this cut off a call midway through?

Comment: It would continue reading until the end of the call unless of course errors occurred.  This would keep reading as long as they keep streaming.  We ended up using a Newtonsoft JsonTextReader instead of reading the raw stream so we could get discreet JSON objects per read but the concept remained the same.